# unable to enable rabbitmq rabbitmq_auth_backend_oauth2 plugin

Tags: plugins, oauth-2.0, rabbitmq

Rabbitmq version 3.8.16

followed [this](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-auth-backend-oauth2) guide.
I tried enabling the plugin.

```
sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_auth_backend_oauth2
```

However it throws back an error.

```
** (CaseClauseError) no case clause matching: {:could_not_start, :jose, {:jose, {{:shutdown, {:failed_to_start_child, :jose_server, {{:case_clause, {:ECPrivateKey, 1, <<104, 152, 88, 12, 19, 82, 251, 156, 171, 31, 222, 207, 0, 76, 115, 88, 210, 229, 36, 106, 137, 192, 81, 153, 154, 254, 226, 38, 247, 70, 226, 157>>, {:namedCurve, {1, 2, 840, 10045, 3, 1, 7}}, <<4, 46, 75, 29, 46, 150, 77, 222, 40, 220, 159, 244, 193, 125, 18, 190, 254, 216, 38, 191, 11, 52, 115, 159, 213, 230, 77, 27, 131, 94, 17, ...>>, :asn1_NOVALUE}}, [{:jose_server, :check_ec_key_mode, 2, [file: 'src/jose_server.erl', line: 189]}, {:lists, :foldl, 3, [file: 'lists.erl', line: 1267]}, {:jose_server, :support_check, 0, [file: 'src/jose_server.erl', line: 153]}, {:jose_server, :init, 1, [file: 'src/jose_server.erl', line: 93]}, {:gen_server, :init_it, 2, [file: 'gen_server.erl', line: 423]}, {:gen_server, :init_it, 6, [file: 'gen_server.erl', line: 390]}, {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file: 'proc_lib.erl', line: 226]}]}}}, {:jose_app, :start, [:normal, []]}}}}
    (rabbitmqctl 3.8.0-dev) lib/rabbitmq/cli/plugins/plugins_helpers.ex:210: RabbitMQ.CLI.Plugins.Helpers.update_enabled_plugins/2
    (rabbitmqctl 3.8.0-dev) lib/rabbitmq/cli/plugins/plugins_helpers.ex:107: RabbitMQ.CLI.Plugins.Helpers.update_enabled_plugins/4
    (rabbitmqctl 3.8.0-dev) lib/rabbitmq/cli/plugins/commands/enable_command.ex:121: anonymous fn/6 in RabbitMQ.CLI.Plugins.Commands.EnableCommand.do_run/2
    (elixir 1.10.4) lib/stream.ex:1325: anonymous fn/2 in Stream.iterate/2
    (elixir 1.10.4) lib/stream.ex:1538: Stream.do_unfold/4
    (elixir 1.10.4) lib/stream.ex:1609: Enumerable.Stream.do_each/4
    (elixir 1.10.4) lib/stream.ex:956: Stream.do_enum_transform/7
    (elixir 1.10.4) lib/stream.ex:1609: Enumerable.Stream.do_each/4

{:case_clause, {:could_not_start, :jose, {:jose, {{:shutdown, {:failed_to_start_child, :jose_server, {{:case_clause, {:ECPrivateKey, 1, <<104, 152, 88, 12, 19, 82, 251, 156, 171, 31, 222, 207, 0, 76, 115, 88, 210, 229, 36, 106, 137, 192, 81, 153, 154, 254, 226, 38, 247, 70, 226, ...>>, {:namedCurve, {1, 2, 840, 10045, 3, 1, 7}}, <<4, 46, 75, 29, 46, 150, 77, 222, 40, 220, 159, 244, 193, 125, 18, 190, 254, 216, 38, 191, 11, 52, 115, 159, 213, 230, 77, 27, 131, ...>>, :asn1_NOVALUE}}, [{:jose_server, :check_ec_key_mode, 2, [file: 'src/jose_server.erl', line: 189]}, {:lists, :foldl, 3, [file: 'lists.erl', line: 1267]}, {:jose_server, :support_check, 0, [file: 'src/jose_server.erl', line: 153]}, {:jose_server, :init, 1, [file: 'src/jose_server.erl', line: 93]}, {:gen_server, :init_it, 2, [file: 'gen_server.erl', line: 423]}, {:gen_server, :init_it, 6, [file: 'gen_server.erl', line: 390]}, {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file: 'proc_lib.erl', line: 226]}]}}}, {:jose_app, :start, [:normal, []]}}}}}
```

Any pointers or documentation for this configuration.

Thanks,
Sajith

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, rabbitmq 3.8.5 seems to work. I assume the plugin built with 3.8.16 has a problem.